# Downgrade cinnamon version

Tags: apt, cinnamon

I upgraded Linux Mint from 20 to 20.2 and it comes with Cinnamon 5.0 uma, which breaks my fractional scaling. The Ubuntu DE doesn't do that.

How can I downgrade back to Cinnamon 4, or configure correctly for fractional scaling?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue with downgrading. Of significance, one has to change the PPA's that are involved.  When doing an upgrade, a new PPA is used that contains the new cinnamon 5 packages, and so to downgrade, one has to use the Ulyanna PPA's that will then only contain cinnamon 4.6 as the highest versions of cinnamon packages. Uninstall all the cinnamon 5 packages using

```
dpkg -l | grep cinnmon | grep 5
```

and

```
dpkg -r package_name
```

to remove them.